# Representing Fraction of Second with ISO 8601:2004

Tags: datetime-format, iso8601

The following is the definition of IS0 8601:2004 standard. It says that the ***fraction of second can be represented with one to six digits.***

Can I use all the 6 digits for representing the fraction of a second?
Are the following Representation correct, if I use 6 digits for representing fraction of a second?

1ms -- 001000
10ms -- 010000
100ms -- 100000

{Extended Time  Format} (32 bytes)
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD
YYYY = Year        0000 to 9999
MM = Month          01 to 12
DD = Day            01 to 31
T  = special separator     T
hh = Hour           00 to 23
mm = Minute         00 to 59
ss = Second         00 to 59
s = one to six digits representing a fraction of a second
TZD  = time zone designator
(TZD is denoted by ‘+hh:mm’, ‘-hh:mm’ or‘Z’)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ISO 8601:2004 doesn't specify the number of digits in the decimal fraction.

**4.2.2.4 Representations with decimal fraction**

> The interchange parties, dependent upon the application, shall agree
>   the number of digits in the decimal fraction. The format shall be
>   [hhmmss,ss], [hhmm,mm] or [hh,hh] as appropriate (hour minute second,
>   hour minute, and hour, respectively), with as many digits as necessary
>   following the decimal sign. A decimal fraction shall have at least one
>   digit.

Yes, your representation is correct if you use 6 digits for the decimal fraction.

```
1ms   -- 001000
10ms  -- 010000
100ms -- 100000
1μs   -- 000001
```