# How to read non-ISO and ISO formatted date-time string in python without dateutils?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have the following three tz-aware `date_str`:

- `"2015-01-08T08:21:43.8082Z"`
- `"2015-01-08T08:21:43.808200Z"`
- `""2015-01-08T08:21:43Z"`

I try and read them in python like so: `datetime.fromisoformat(date_str.replace('Z', '+00:00'))`, however this fails for the first one.

I guess it's because the first is not ISO formatted.

My question is: is there a fast way in python (without 3rd party methods) to read all three types of tz aware date strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the first example, you can do

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str.replace("Z","+00:00"),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

Which will, incidentally, also handle the second example.

But that still entails choosing a different parser for different formats. So you have three choices.

1. You write code (using, say, a regular expression) to examine the string you get and call an appropriate function to parse it.
2. You clean up the input by adding trailing zeroes to the milliseconds to make it acceptable to `fromisoformat`, much as you are already doing to fix up the timezone. You can do that like this:

   ```
   datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_str.replace("Z",".000000+00:00"[len(date_str)-20:]))
   ```

   which will work with all 3 of your formats, and some other variations on the millisecond precision besides. Though in a code review I would reject that approach because I think it is brittle.
3. If you want a parser that is flexible enough to deal with minor variations in the input on its own, well, that is what `dateutil` is for.

The flexibility to handle arbitrary nonstandard formats has to be somewhere. Either you write it or you import it.

I would back `dateutil` against any implementation that I could write, because it is bound to deal better with input I don't expect. But you might come to a different conclusion.

Comment: Could be added that you have trade in efficiency for dateutil's convenience. Kind of a pain that Python is that picky when it comes to the microseconds... works so nicely in [other languages](https://play.golang.org/p/EohcxB4pt7b).

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't think one can complain too much about a function called `fromisoformat()` insisting that the presented string should in fact be in ISO format. It is not Python that is picky about microseconds; it is the ISO standard. But as you point out, there is a good argument for suggesting that `datetime` should also have a `fromrfc3339()` function.

Comment: are you sure ISO 8601 specifies exact/allowed number of fractional seconds? E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25842840/10197418) suggests otherwise; unfortunately I don't have access to the most recent version ISO 8601-2:2019

Comment: I've checked and you are entirely correct. The number of decimals *can* be flexible, but  only "by mutual agreement": it does not require acceptance of anything the other party might send. The standard library permits 0, 3 or 6 decimals in seconds and none at all in hours or minutes. That is reasonable: there is no such thing as a deci-hour or a deciminute, and 4 decimals of seconds also doesn't have an SI name.